# C# Entity Framework - Order by and Take

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, select, sql-order-by

I am trying to select 5 oldest entries from my database. I am using the following statement:

```
dbContext.Items.Take(5).OrderBy(i => i.LastCheck).ToListAsync();
```

The problem here is that EF first takes the first 5 Items from the table, and then sorts them. So I always get the 5 first entries from the table. But I want it first to sort the items and then select the top 5 ones, like when I execute this sql command:

```
select top 5 * from Items order by LastCheck asc
```

Here I get the right result.

Is there a possibility to do that in EF or do I have to execute the query?

Comment: Order the items first, then Take...

Comment: Just switch your `OrderBy()` and `Take()`.

Comment: Just exchange the position of orderby and take....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to switch `Take()` and `OrderBy()`

```
dbContext.Items.OrderBy(i => i.LastCheck).Take(5).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Interesting. Since i ordered by 2 parameters (OrderBy(i => i.LastCheck).ThenBy...) i tried to put the Take(5) between them two and i got an error, but I didnt try to put the Take at the end. Thats it, thanks

Comment: `ThenBy()` requires a `IOrderedEnumerable` which is provided by `OrderBy()` but not by `Take()`

Comment: You could write your two orderings as follows `dbcontext.Items.OrderBy(x=> x.LastCheck).Take(5).OrderBy(y=> y.someProp)` This way, the second `OrderBy` will only have to sort the remaining 5 items, but of course will destroy your ordering by LastCheck.

Answer (score 0):

Think this has already been answered above but:-

```
dbContext.Items.OrderBy(x=>x.LastCheck).Take(5).ToListAsync();
```

Doing take first, would select your top 5 items from the list, and then sort just those 5, whereas what you want to do, is sort the list first into date order and then take the top 5.

Similarly if you wanted to sort by newest first that above query (to ensure it is sorted) would become:-

```
dbContext.Items.OrderByDescending(x=>x.LastCheck).Take(5).ToListAsync();
```

Hope this helps!